Azure Function App Fails to Delete Blob Image After Deployment
I have an Azure Function app designed to delete a blob image in Azure Storage. The function is mapped to the storage account and works perfectly when run locally, pointing to the Azure storage account.
Details:

NET version: .NET 8
Source code: C#
Environment variables: Set both locally and in Azure, mapping the URL and the storage connection string
Issue: After deploying the function to Azure, it fails to delete the blob image. The same environment variables are set in Azure as they are when executed locally.

Error Message:
Exception while executing function: EliminarImagen Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory.Data, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried on the deployment mode setting set the function as

Framework-dependent
Self-contained

The target runtime setted as

win-x64
portable

But always get the same error...
This is the .csproj file:
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.22.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Memory.Data" Version="8.0.1" />

Maybe I'm missing something, but I ran out of ideas, the code that executes the deletion of the blob is this:
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FuncionEliminarImagenes.Clases
 {
    public static class EliminarImagen
    {
        [FunctionName("EliminarImagen")]
         public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = 
"eliminaImagen/{containerName}/{imageName}")] HttpRequest req, string containerName, 
string imageName, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Initializing the function, ready to receive requests...");

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(Conexion.connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        // Check if container exists
        if (!await containerClient.ExistsAsync())
        {
            log.LogError($"The container {containerName} does not exist.");
            return new NotFoundObjectResult($"The container {containerName} does not exist.");
        }

        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(imageName);
        log.LogInformation($"Attempting to delete the image: {imageName} in the container: {containerName}");

        if (!await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
        {
            log.LogWarning($"The image {imageName} does not exist in the container {containerName}.");
            return new NotFoundObjectResult($"The image {imageName} does not exist in the container {containerName}.");
        }
        else
        {
            var deleteResponse = await blobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
            if (deleteResponse)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"The image {imageName} was deleted from the container {containerName}.");
                return new OkObjectResult($"The image {imageName} was successfully deleted.");
            }
            return new StatusCodeResult(200);
        }
    }
}

}

You need to update your function to work with .net 8.  I am assuming you are using the Isolated Process Model. I ran into this recently as well.
You need to update the app to use the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker packages instead of the WebJobs pacakges.
This MS article describes how to update.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8

thanks!! that worked just fine, I migrated the function from in process model to isolated and now it's working.
